# Statically link openssl in Visual C++ malloc warning

Tags: c++, winapi, openssl

The OpenSSL 1.0.2g package's INSTALL.W32 documentation has the following warning text:

> One final comment about compiling applications linked to the OpenSSL library.
>    If you don't use the multithreaded DLL runtime library (/MD option) your
>    program will almost certainly crash because malloc gets confused -- the
>    OpenSSL DLLs are statically linked to one version, the application must
>    not use a different one.

I don't fully understand this or the repercussions of it. Are they saying that statically linking libeay32mt.lib is not supported?

We are experiencing random crashes in our app and the stack trace sometimes point to free calls in openssl functions, would that be the expected symptom that this warning refers to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C and C++ memory management is implemented in the CRT (C Runtime Library). Each physical copy of the CRT mapped into a process (either statically compiled into a module, or referenced DLL) uses a distinct heap. Memory allocations and deallocations must be performed on the same heap, i.e. the same physical CRT copy (see [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx) for more details).

In your specific scenario you need to make sure to do the following:

- Dynamically link your application against the OpenSSL DLLs.
- Dynamically link your application against the CRT.
- Verify that both your application and the OpenSSL DLLs link against identical versions of the CRT (version and configuration).

While it is possible to statically link against OpenSSL, if you can ensure that your final binary contains a single CRT implementation and doesn't (directly or indirectly) dynamically link against the CRT as well. This is difficult to maintain, and breaks as soon as you link against a library, that doesn't provide a static library.